# BufferedImage pixels Vs Graphics.drawImage

Tags: java, image, graphics, pixel

What is the difference between making a Buffered Image, and drawing on its pixels using:

```
private BufferedImage img;
private int[] pixels;

pixels = ((DataBufferInt) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer());
```

And just using a Image for the

```
img
```

Variable And using img's graphics to do:

```
img.getGraphics().drawImage(/*image*/, x, y, observer);
```

EDIT:

This is for game development!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Advantages of going via the `Graphics` methods:

- It's usually **simpler** to use the ready-made higher level operations like `drawImage`
- You may benefit from **hardware acceleration / optimisations** on some platforms
- It works relatively **independently** of the underlying image format

Advantages of going down to the pixel buffer level:

- It can be useful for very **specialised purposes**, e.g. generating each pixel from some sort of formula / calculation (I use this technique to generate custom colour gradients, for example)
- It can be *marginally* faster for **individual pixel operations** (but likely to be slower for bulk operations like `drawImage`, because you don't get the hardware acceleration)

If it's just regular in-game rendering of a screen, I'd say the `Graphics` route is probably best. If you're doing something fancy like on-the-fly image generation, then the pixel buffer route can be worth exploring.

Answer (score 5):

- Using `getGraphics()` provides a reliable way to draw on an image regardless of its underlying structure.
- Note that you should not do this via chaining as you demonstrate: `img.getGraphics().drawImage(/*image*/, x, y, observer);` since this does not allow you to dispose of the Graphics object once you're done with it, risking your running out of resources.
- Directly manipulating your raster's bits is possibly a quicker way to change things, but I believe that how you do this is dependent on the type of BufferedImage you are using.

Comment: Both this and @mikera's answers are good and seem to favor `drawImage()`. I like this answer as it mentions the `dispose()` issue, which is important. It's probably also worth mentioning that accessing the raster/data buffer directly as in the OP, may disable sw/hw optimizations for the image instance's lifetime (!), so use with care. And whenever in doubt, profile. :-)